# The QT wallet does not start

Tags: bitcoin-core, installation

The QT wallet does not start:

```
./bitcoin-qt в ubuntu 20.04?  qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "offscreen" in ""                                                  

This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.                                                                                                         

Available platform pl
```

tell me how to solve the problem? I installed dependencies with githab bitcoin core.

Answer (score 1):

If the "offscreen" plugin is missing, you may need to rebuild Qt with the necessary platform plugins. First, ensure you have the Qt source code:

````
 ```bash
 git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
 cd qt5
 git checkout <qt_version_tag>  # Replace <qt_version_tag> with the desired version tag, e.g., 5.15.2
 ```
````

- Then configure and build Qt with the necessary platform plugins:

  ```bash
  ./configure -prefix /path/to/qt -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests
  make
  make install
  ```

  Replace `/path/to/qt` with the desired installation path.

After rebuilding Qt, you can follow the previous steps to rebuild Bitcoin Core and run it. This should ensure that the required Qt platform plugins, including "offscreen," are available.

Remember to replace `<qt_version_tag>` with the actual version tag of the Qt version you want to build.